# read outlook email in C# using pop3 (in korean)

Tags: c#, email, pop3, openpop

I want to read outlook email in C# using pop3. 
when i get message from my mailbox, there is encoding exception because i read korean email.
how can i read korean email?
And Can i set mailbox that i want to read?
please help me

```
    class Program
    {
        static Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client();
        static StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 995, true);
            client.Authenticate("blahblahblah", "blahblahblah");//로그인

            Console.WriteLine("Checking Inbox");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            var count = client.GetMessageCount();//몇개의 메세지가 있는지
            Console.WriteLine(count);

            for (int i=count;i>=1;i--)
            {
                var message = client.GetMessage(i);
                var fromAddress = message.Headers.From.Address;
                var subject = message.Headers.Subject;
                var messageBody = String.Empty;

                var plainText = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();

                if (plainText == null)
                {
                    var html = message.FindFirstHtmlVersion();
                    messageBody = html.GetBodyAsText();
                }
                else
                {
                    messageBody = plainText.GetBodyAsText();
                }
                table.Rows.Add(i,subject, fromAddress, messageBody);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please also post the exception message. makes helping easier :)

Comment: You have to specify exactly where it breaks, what error you get...

Comment: @AngryHacker it break at
var message = client.GetMessage(i);

Comment: @Jan  System.ArgumentException: ''ks_c_5601-1987' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. ' this is my exception message. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow.
As per my understanding, you are using OpenPop.NET library.

OpenPop.NET uses EncodingFinder class to find correct encoding. By default it supports only utf8 and ascii (at least reading library code at github).
According to this page:
http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleChangeCharacterSetMapping.php
you can add your encoding(s) to EncodingFinder.
In your case, all you have to do is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   EncodingFinder.AddMapping("ks_c_5601-1987", Encoding.GetEncoding(949));
   // rest of the application
```

Please note this will work only on .NET Framework, not in .NET Core, since the latter supports a really limited number of encodings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=netcore-3.1).

I do not have a Korean pop3 on which to test this solution, but I hope it will work. Good luck!

**Edit after some search**
It should be possible to work with Korean encoding in .NET Core also, it's just a little trickier:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
   EncodingFinder.AddMapping("ks_c_5601-1987", Encoding.GetEncoding(949));
   // rest of application
```

Give it a try, if you are working with .NET Core.

Comment: working !!!! Thank you very much :)
Hmm. May I ask you one more question?
I want to read the mail in a specific inbox, not in the inbox!
Is it possible to set a mailbox in pop3 ??

Comment: Not as my knowledge (I could be wrong). I think you'll need to go IMAP for that.

Comment: Hi may i ask about IMAP?

Comment: I would create different question, if I were you. Since this question is about pop3, and answered, should be considered closed. Also, comments are not the best way to ask and explain things, on SO.